# Extracting and Sorting data from pdf using C# package

Tags: c#, json, pdf, serialization

I'm working on a project where I have to extract specific text from a pdf so that I can send these info into an excel file.
I tried at first to convert my pdf into a .txt file thinking a .txt file format would be easier to convert into json.
But the result is not at all what I need (dictionary-style Json format) but instead a kind of giant messy string .
The pdf  sample looks like this:

Analysis

Some text

Reference Date       (Big space)            11/17/2021

Reference Price      (Big space)            USD 745

Client id            (Big space)            4572845

I'd like to have something like this at the end:

{Analysis:Some text, Reference Date:11/17/2021, Reference Price:USD 745, Client id:4572845}

Currently the results give all the info mixed up between each others.

Here is my code:

First, I created a "Global" class where I will create the method "Extract_Row_Info_TS that will basically load the first page of the document (called a TS or Termsheet) and extract the text from the PDF and store it into a txt file called "result.txt":

```
class Global
{
    public static void Extract_RowInfo_TS(string  doc_Type, string docPath, int? nbrPage = null)
    {
        switch (doc_Type)
        {
            case "Pdf":
                Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument doc = new Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument();
                doc.LoadFromFile(docPath);
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            
                //Extract text from the first page only
                Spire.Pdf.PdfPageBase pagefirst = doc.Pages[0];
                buffer.Append(pagefirst.ExtractText());
               
                doc.Close();
            
                //save text
                String fileName = @"my_disk:\my_path\result.txt";
                File.WriteAllText(fileName, buffer.ToString());
            
                //Load File
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
                break;

            case "Excel":
                Spire.Xls.Workbook Wb = new Spire.Xls.Workbook();
                break;
            case "Word":
                Spire.Doc.Document doc_word = new Spire.Doc.Document();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Come back to my main page, I call the above method "Extract_RowInfo_TS" from above Global class and when it created "result.txt" from the pdf infos, I'll try to convert this "result.txt"  into a json format:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Extract_PDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Global.Extract_RowInfo_TS("Pdf", @"my_disk:\my_path\my_doc.pdf");
        Convert_To_Json_Format(@"my_disk:\my_path\result.txt"); 
    }

    private void Convert_To_Json_Format(string baseTextFile)
    {
        string streamText = new StreamReader(baseTextFile).ReadToEnd();
    
        //Serialize Json Data.
        string serializeData = Serialize_into_Json(streamText);
        string newFile = @"my_disk:\my_path\NEW_text_file_2.txt";
        File.WriteAllText(newFile, serializeData);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newFile);

    }

    private static string Serialize_into_Json(string json)
    {
        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
        return jsonData;
    }
}
```

I'm stuck here trying to create a proper json format file (or anything alike actually, I just want to group info between them, maybe create a table first ? I don't know...) that I can use for sending into my Excel file. Any help would be much appreciated ! I'm using the  Free version of Spire Nuget package v4.3.1 that contains Free Spire.PDF, Spire.Xls, Spire.Doc and more of them. But maybe there are some others solutions out there to achieve the goal I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for helping and have a great day.

Comment: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Extract/Read/Extract-Text-from-PDF-Document-using-SimpleTextExtractionStrategy.html

Comment: Hey tahnks for answering. Unfortunately, it still give some text file with this kind of output:

Indicative Product Terms
        Trade Date                                  16 November 2021
        Expiry                                       17 May 2022
        Underlying                                  EUR/USD

And still big spaces between Trade Date and 16 Novembre 2021 for example

Comment: You can directly convert the PDF to Excel: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Program-Guide/Conversion/Convert-PDF-to-Excel-in-C-VB.NET.html

Comment: @DheerajMalik thanks for your remarks. It's actually doable if you have the commercial version of Spire.Office. I'm using the free version of Spire.Office which includes .PDF, .Xls, .Doc among other features but not this one unfortunately... However, I manage to get a .txt file that is quite proper. Only get  some headaches with extra spaces. But I'm honestly open to any solution that could help me to extract the text within a pdf and store it somewhere I can sort the info I extracted